# Naming of types when using an ORM

Tags: orm, naming, oop

I am working on a project where a number of types have the suffix "Instance".

For example, we have the concept of tabs in the application, so we have a *TabInstance* type.

To me this seems redundant and even confusing / wrong, as there is already the concept of an instance in OO terminology.

The system uses nHibernate as an ORM - I wonder if such a naming scheme is something that is typical in systems using ORMs, or is used or some other reason?

Comment: Redundant and not standard as far as I'm aware.

Comment: thanks, thought so, but wanted to check before i stuck my neck out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, we have the concept of
>   **tabs** in the application, so we have a TabInstance type.

It seems as if you should have the type Tab instead of TabInstance.

Answer (score 1):

yes get rid of them.